# How to calculate the Probability for the Unconditional Node in the Bayesian Belief Network?

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-networks

In the popular example for Bayesian Belief network **[Burglary Alarm](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-950j-biomedical-computing-fall-2010/lectures-and-readings/MITHST_950JF10_lec14.pdf)** how is the probability for burglary P(B) and earthquake P(E) calculated as 0.001 and 0.002 respectively?

Is it an assumption made or there is some calculation involved ? I can understand the conditional probabilities for the child nodes but not sure how the probability for the nodes Burglary and Earthquake are getting calculated?

Comment: Just looking at the slide deck. I think they are Priors (just known a priori). Assumptions, if you will. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, *Burglary* and *Earthquake* only have prior probabilities in the Bayes net. These priors are not calculated from other variables/distributions. They are just assumptions in this example, or, sugarcoated, expert knowledge. In fact, it is often hard to find good priors (from expert knowledge). Extracting them from large non-biased datasets can help. Anyway, one needs to understand the dataset and the context/circumstances/constraints of its collection.